# $p_n:S^1\to S^1$ is a covering

Tags: algebraic-topology

I just started learning about covering spaces and was hoping someone could fill in the details for me with this particular example.

We think of $S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$ and define $p_n:S^1\to S^1$ by $p_n(z)=z^n$. Then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $p_n$ is a covering.

The hint is to observe that $S^1-${$x$} is evenly covered by $p_n$ for all $x\in S^1$, but I don't see why this is true, and I'm not sure why this would imply that $S^1-${$x$} is a covering. Could someone please explain?

Comment: What is the definition of covering that you have?

Comment: $p:X\to Y$ is a covering if for any $y\in Y$ there is an open neighborhood of $V$ of $y$ such that $p^{-1}(V)$ is the disjoint union of open sets in $X$, and the restriction of $p$ to any one of these open sets is homeomorphism onto $V$.

Comment: What what is your definition of «evenly covered»?

Comment: $V\subset Y$ is evenly covered by $p$ if $p^{-1}(V)$ is the disjoint union of open sets in $X$ and the restriction of $p$ to any one of these open-sets is a homeomorphism onto $V$

Comment: Ok. So according to your definitions, to show that $p_n$ is a covering you have to show that every point of its codomain has a neighborhood that is evenly covered: that is precisely the content of the hint.

Comment: Right, but I don't see why $S^1-${$x$} is evenly covered by $p_n$.

Comment: What is the preimage of $S^1-\{x\}$ under $p_n$?

Comment: All $z\in S^1$ such that $z^n$ is not $x$.

Comment: Why is this open and homeomorphic to $S^1-${$x$} though?

Comment: It is open. It is not homeomorphic to $S^1-\{x\}$.

Comment: Oops, I meant the restriction of p to any one of the disjoint open sets is homeomorphic to $S^1-${$x$}. Pictorially, what would the preimage look like as a subset $S^1$?

Comment: try to do a picture yourself. To fix ideas, let $x=1$ and make a drawing!

Comment: So for $x=1$, you get $S^1-${nth roots of unity}. So for any other $x\in S^1$, $S^1-${$x$} gives you a similar picture?